# How to kill the tail -f process after finding the special string?

Tags: shell, grep

How can I kill the tail process after having found special command

```
tail -f filename | grep -m1 " special string" | tee txtfile
```

After founding the "special string" the tail function needs to be killed to execute the rest of the program.

Comment: [How to stop the tail when sed finds the string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615395/how-to-stop-the-tail-when-sed-finds-the-string) -- same class?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop the tail when sed finds the string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615395/how-to-stop-the-tail-when-sed-finds-the-string)