# How to stop the tail when sed finds the string?

Tags: shell, tail

I want to terminate the `tail` command after having the match found and until then all the lines are written to another file.

```
tail -f logfile | sed '/special string/q'  | tee output.txt
```

Output.txt will have the lines until special string is found. But the problem is, after that I want to end the `tail` command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tail a log util keywords found or timeout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527543/tail-a-log-util-keywords-found-or-timeout)

Comment: In my experimentation, it seems like `tail -f` hangs around only until its sleep interval ends. So, in order to make it terminate faster, invoke it with `--sleep-interval=N`, e.g. `tail -f -s 0.01 logfile | sed '/special string/q'  | tee output.txt`.

Comment: my script still is in the same  line, it is not terminating there. @Amir

Comment: Is your pattern, `special string`, matching anything in the log file when interpreted as a regular expression?

Comment: yes, it matches and writes the lines to output.txt file till "special string" matches. But tail -f function , I thinks still is not terminated., because the program is struck on this line.

Comment: Please provide actual data and the actual pattern that you are using. Don't provide placeholder values. Since at least three people have asked about this specific thing today, we must assume that it is a school assignment. As a school assignment, the data probably does not contain personal details that needs to be censored.

Comment: { sed '/.special string/q' | tee "$output" ;   kill -s PIPE "$!"; } < <(exec tail -f logfile) gives me the solution for the problem @kusalananda

Comment: @AbhaySingh If you're using `bash`, then mention that in the question. If you have found a solution, then post it as an answer along with an explanation of the issue and of how your solution solves the issue.

Comment: You may also want to mention what Unix you are using.

Comment: [How to kill the tail -f process after finding the special string?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615388/how-to-kill-the-tail-f-process-after-finding-the-special-string) -- same class?

Comment: @glenn does it matter? do *you* know any reliable way from a pipe reader to kill the pipe writer, which does not depend on `/proc` filesystem, does not assume that they're both part of the same process group, does not assume that pipes aren't implemented with sockets (as in ksh), and will **happen immediately**, not when the writer tries to write something else (which may never come).

Comment: use a different command in place of `sed`, one that will terminate when done. When it terminates the pipes will be closed, and `tail` will exit. consider `awk`.

Answer (score 6):

#### You should kill it explicitly

```
seq 1 10 > file
tail -f file | { sed /7/q; pkill -PIPE -xg0 tail; } | tee output
```

`pkill -PIPE -xg0 tail` means

> send a `SIGPIPE` signal to the process named exactly `tail` from the same process group as ourselves.

This assumes that there is no other `tail` running in the same process group. If the command is run from an interactive terminal (from a shell with job control), it should be safe, as each pipeline is then run in its own process group (aka job). In a shell without job control (e.g. in a script), we could wrap the pipeline in a separate shell where the job control is explicitly turned on:

```
sh -mc 'tail -f file | { sed /7/q; pkill -PIPE -xg0 tail; }' | tee output
```

#### But GNU tail kills itself

If you're using a Linux machine with bash and coreutils, you will notice that everything falls into place, and there's no need of any `kill` whatsoever; `tail` will simply terminate by itself:

```
debian$ tail -f file | sed /2/q
1
2
debian$ # WOW!
```

That's because the `tail` from GNU coreutils is using a smart trick to determine if its stdout is still *writable*: it's polling it for a "ready for *reading*" condition, which on the writing end of a pipe will only happen in case of error, as when its other end has been closed. If that's the case, then `tail` just kills itself with a `SIGPIPE` signal. Quoting from its [source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c?id=175c7c6a60c562e1972199ae980a1bcd7027105e#n345):

```c
  FD_SET (STDOUT_FILENO, &rfd);

  /* readable event on STDOUT is equivalent to POLLERR,
     and implies an error condition on output like broken pipe.  */
  if (select (STDOUT_FILENO + 1, &rfd, NULL, NULL, &delay) == 1)
    die_pipe ();
```

[In fact, other systems may `POLLHUP` or `POLLHUP|POLLIN` instead of `POLLERR`, but this doesn't matter in practice]

GNU tail only does this on pipes, not on sockets or ttys (which means that that doesn't work with ksh93, which is using kneecapped unix-domain sockets to implement its "pipes").

Also (AFAIK) only GNU `tail` does this at all, and only since version [8.28](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=ce0415fda108b7ec35181118fd7a2c9ee70331ee); even on Linux, busybox `tail` does not.

That means that using `tail -f | quit_at_some_point` (from many answers here) is still very much hit-and-miss, and may actually never terminate.

Answer (score 2):

Given the following `logfile`:

```
one
two
three
special string
four
```

And the following command

```
$ tail -f logfile | sed '/special string/q'  | tee output.txt
```

I get the following output:

```
one
two
three
special string
```

And then *both* `tail` and `sed` exit successfully. So your own example, at least on my computer, works exactly as you described. To further verify this, given the following file

```
one
two
three
four
```

I get no output, and the command hangs, waiting for the `special string`. When I, then, add it using the command `echo special string >> logfile` from a separate terminal, the original command succesfully exits again.

So everything seems to work correctly, right? If not, please let me know what you expected. In any case, thank you for learning me a cool new trick which I will undoubtedly use in the future!

Comment: It works for you because the `tail` from coreutils (the default on Linux) does a very smart `select()` trick to determine if its stdout pipe is still writable , and if it's not, it kills itself with `SIGPIPE`. That's unfortunately **not** the case everywhere.

Comment: Interesting! Where can I learn more about this trick?

Comment: See the [source code](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c?id=175c7c6a60c562e1972199ae980a1bcd7027105e#n365). Unfortunately, that doesn't work with a shell like ksh93, which is using Unix sockets to implement its pipes.