# awk behaving different with tail vs inotifywait

Tags: awk, tail, inotify

`awk` behaves differently when analyzing the output of `tail -f` versus `inotifywait -m`. Specifically I am searching for a matching string and want to exit `awk` once it appears. This works fine for `tail -f`, however in the case of `inofitywait`, `awk` needs to be triggered twice. Why so?

---

**Reproducible Examples:**

Say we are searching for a specific string ("OPEN") in either case and use a special exit code as marker. Let's also trigger it after a short wait (`inotofywait` needs a moment) and return the exit code. Pseudo-code:

```
 command | awk-analysis || get-non-0-exit-code & trigger
```

**All good for `tail -f`**

The following a) prints the line, b) returns the exit code and c) terminates. As expected.

```
tail -f test.file | awk '/OPEN/ { print $0 ; exit 100 }' || echo $? &
  { sleep 2 ; echo OPEN > test.file ; }
```

**However with `inotifywait -m`**

the result is quite different.

```
inotifywait -m -e OPEN | awk '/OPEN/ { print $0 ; exit 100 }' || echo $? &
  { sleep 2 ; touch test.file ; }
```

This will print the line (so `inotifywait` is triggered and `awk` sees it) but NOT show the exit code nor terminate. Only another trigger like `touch test.file` is able to stop `awk`

**Maybe control characters?**

I thought maybe I am missing a singal `awk` uses here, so I tried to analyze with `cat -A` (results file in parent folder, so otherwise a second "OPEN" is triggered in `inotifywait`):

```
tail -f test.file | tee >(cat -A >../stream) | ....
cat ../stream
OPEN$
```

and

```
inotifywait -m -e OPEN | tee >(cat -A >../stream) | ....
cat ../stream
./ OPEN test.file$
```

So no unseen control characters missed.

**What is the reason for this behaviour?**

Am I missing a newline? How comes `awk` does print the line, but not run the `exit` command in the same code block? Why does it work with `tail`, though?

---

*Verisons*

`awk --verison` : GNU Awk 4.2.1, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.1.2)

`inotifywait -h` : inotifywait 3.14

`tail --verison` : tail (GNU coreutils) 8.30

---

EDIT due to Kusalananda's comments:

**tail -f**

`test.file` exists and has the following content:

*case 1

```
OPEN
spam
```

*case 2

```
spam
OPEN
```

*case 3 (file is empty)

Trigger as above is NOT run, i.e.

```
tail -f test.file | awk '/OPEN/ {print $0 ; exit 100 }' || echo $?
```

Case 1 & 2 : immediately returns the matching line, exit code and is terminated.

Case 3: waits, open other terminal and `echo OPEN >> 3` or `echo OPEN > 3` returns string, exit code and terminates.

Comment: With the `tail -f` example, is the line containing `OPEN` the last line in the file? If not, try again with `OPEN` only on the last line of that file. Also try with _appending_ `OPEN` to the file instead of truncating it. In either case, the left hand side would not terminate immediately just because `awk` exits, it would need to try (and fail) to write across the pipe.

Comment: My answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/616346/414777) explains why that only works with *GNU* tail, what extra stuff GNU tail does for it to work, and how you can make it work with any `tail` implementation (which would work with `inotifywait` too).

Comment: @Kusalananda see edit.

Comment: @Fiximan I think Kamil is on the right track in their answer, assuming you're using GNU tools.

Comment: @Kusalananda Indeed.

Comment: your exemples are not the same: the tail one : you add "OPEN" in the file (clobbering it inthe process, as you "> file" and not ">>file" ...) and for the other : you just touch the file but do not add "OPEN" in it, so awk doesn't see "OPEN" and thus doesn'"t execute its exit 100

Comment: @OlivierDulac "OPEN" is a result from the output of `inotifywait`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo $?` runs after the entire pipeline (the code before `||`) terminates.

In the case of `inotifywait … | awk … || echo …` after `awk` terminates `inotifywait` still runs. It will get `SIGPIPE` only if (when) it tries to write more. Try `touch test.file` again to get to this point and trigger `echo`.

On the other hand `tail` in `tail -f … | awk …` terminates immediately after `awk` exits because [GNU `tail` takes special steps to detect this situation](https://superuser.com/a/1405010/432690).

---

In order to reproduce this with inotifywait, one would need to forward the PID and send a SIGPIPE via awk:

```
{ inotifywait  -m -e OPEN ./  & echo $! ; } |
awk 'NR==1 {pid=$0}
     /OPEN/ {print $0,pid
             system("echo kill -13 "pid)
             exit 122  }' ||
echo $?
```